# When does the compiler need to compute an alias?

Tags: c++, compilation, language-lawyer, alias, standards

Consider the following code:

```
template <class T>
struct computation {
    using type = /* something based on T that takes time to compile */;
};
```

Now consider two codes:

```
using x = computation<T>;
```

and:

```
using y = typename computation<T>::type;
```

I am wondering whether the standard implies that:

- **Option A)** Any "reasonable" compiler will lead to a quick compile time for `x` and long compile time for `y`
- **Option B)** A compiler could totally compute `computation<T>::type` even if only `computation<T>` is called, leading to long compile-time even for `x`

In other words, I am trying to know if the standard specifies anything that would most likely translate into option A or option B for a "reasonable" compiler implemeter. I know that the standard says nothing about compiler implementation but for example if it requires that `::type` does not have to exist until it's specifically called, that would be in favor of option A.

**NOTE:** In my experience, I am pretty sure that `g++`, `clang++`, `msvc`, and `intel` are following option A), but I have no idea whether it's just by pure luck of it's related to something in the standard.

Comment: Someone may prove me wrong here, but consider the possibility that the standard says nothing of _compilation speed_ when determining a type.

Comment: I know that and that is not what I am trying to know. But if the standards says that `::type` does not really "exist" until it's called would be a strong indication.

Comment: I think the compiler has to take option B because it has to make sure that `computation<T>::type` actually gives something sensible when matching T. But maybe just try it. Make ::type fail for a T and see if `using x = computation<T>;` still works.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow See the added note

Comment: iirc, the standard requires a minimum stack depth (which is really small), but compilers can provide a deeper stack depth if they want.

Comment: I don't know if it is explicitly specified anywhere in the standard, the template section and ODR are somewhat mind hurting sections to read, but the as-if rule gives compilers a lot of leeway and I would expect option A was what most/all compilers use.  If something is never used, there is no reason for the compiler to actually do the work.

Comment: @NathanOliver What if the ::type gives an error for the given T that is only apparent when you do the work and therefore the template deduction should fail?

Comment: Is `T` in the two `using` lines supposed to be an actual type or another template parameter? In the former case `typename` doesn't make sense there and in the latter case, neither line by itself will cause any instantiations of anything.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Compilers are allowed to do work that's not strictly necessary, but they can't reject valid programs. Since `computation<T>` by itself not an explicit or implicit instantiation, the validity of `type` does not matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that `T` is an actual non-dependent type here and not another template parameter.

---

The line

```
using x = computation<T>;
```

does not cause implicit instantiation of `computation<T>`. There is therefore no reason for a compiler to try to compute `type` at this point, in particular since any instantiation failure would need to be ignored. The program may not fail to compile if `type`'s computation would yield an invalid type or would otherwise fail.

The line

```
using y = computation<T>::type;
```

does require implicit instantiation of `computation<T>` because the scope resolution operator is applied to it. The implicit instantiation includes computation of type aliases inside `computation<T>`. The compiler *must* perform the computation, because if the computation failed or would yield an invalid type, then the program would be ill-formed and the compiler would need to diagnose it.

This doesn't actually dependent on the `::type` part specifically. Even if it was `::type2` for another type alias, the implicit instantiation of the class template specialization will require computation of `type`.

Similarly using `computation<T>` in any other context requiring it to be complete will require implicit instantiation and therefore computation of `type`, e.g.

```
auto z = computation<T>{};
```